# Need to connect multiple 3.5" hard drives to the Thunderbolt port of a 2012 iMac

Tags: hard-drive, imac, thunderbolt

I have a 2012 iMac that I'm currently using as a file server. I need to connect several 3.5" hard drives to it, and its USB 3 ports are currently used up with other devices. So what I'd like to do is connect something like  an external enclosure with multiple drive bays (as many as four) to the Thunderbolt 1 port of this iMac.

So far I haven't been able to find a singular device that'll let me do it, and I'm not sure if I can pull it off with adapters. For example, there are now many USB-C multi-bay hard drive enclosures, but I'm not confident I'd be able to use it with a 2012 iMac.

Is there either a) a device, possibly an old one I could get used, that connects multiple hard drives to a Thunderbolt port, or b) an adapter I can use to connect a more modern multi-bay enclosure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting an [OWC ThunderBay 4](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/thunderbay-4) and an Apple Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter. It's been working great with my 2012 iMac, and I feel future-proofed in case I update to a computer that has Thunderbolt 3 ports.

Comment: Is this allowing you to see, mount and access them as separate drives? If so, can you read/write to multiple drives in the enclosure simultaneously? From one drive in the enclosure to another in the same enclosure?

Comment: @Rivka Yes I can access all of the drives individually and copy files between them. It's like they're all connected using individual external enclosures.